# PHP - Display message from MySQL directly after selecting a dropdown with values of Mysql

Tags: php, html

Oopss sorry, i forgot to change it. in this code it will display the list of cakename.

```
<?php
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY c_id ASC";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$c_id=$rows['c_id']; // idnumber of cake
$cakename=$rows['cakename']; //this is the name of cake
$options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$c_id\">$cakename</OPTION>"; //it will list all the cake
// close while loop 
}
?>

<select name="order_id">
<option value=0>Select Cake:<?php echo $options; ?>
</select>
```

and this one, when the user selected the cake1.it will show the details,price and the picture.thats my problem.i want to combine all the code.and i dont know how to show the picture.

```
<html>
<form action="current_file.php" method="POST">
<select name="order_id" id="order_id" onChange="this.form.submit()">
<option value="">Select Cake:</options>
<option value="1">cake1</options>
<option value="2">cake2</options>
<option value="3">cake3</options>
</select>
</form>

<?php

$order_id=$_POST['order_id']; 

if (!empty($order_id)){

   $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE c_id = $order_id";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $price=$rows['price'];
        $details=$rows['details'];
        $picture=$rows['picture'];
       // close while loop 
     }
     echo $details;
echo $price;
}//close if statement

?>
```

yeah, all the codes are working.but all i want is to become one.get it?? like this but not working:

```
<?php
  $order_id=$_POST['order_id']; 

    if (!empty($order_id)){
    $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE c_id = $order_id";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    $price=$rows['price'];
    $details=$rows['details'];
    $picture=$rows['picture'];
    $c_id=$rows['c_id']; // idnumber of cake
    $cakename=$rows['cakename']; //this is the name of cake
    $options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$c_id\">$cakename</OPTION>"; //it will list all the cake
    // close while loop 
    }
    ?>

    <form action="current_file.php" method="POST">
    <select name="order_id" id="order_id" onChange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value=0>Select Cake:<?php echo $options; ?>
    </select>
<?php
    echo $details;
    echo $price;
    echo $picture; 
?>
</form>
```

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? Also, you shouldn't be using the `mysql_*` functions, they're deprecated in PHP5.5

Comment: what's the question? piece of cake?

Comment: unless that second query only ever returns one result row, you'll have to move your echoes INSIDE the loop. Which then begs the question: if the query does return only one row, why the foreach loop? Cargo-cult programming?

Comment: Seriously, I answered the question but now that I'm reading the question again, I'm not sure what's the question!

Answer (score 0):

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $c_id=$rows['c_id'];
    $options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$c_id\">$cakename</OPTION>";
    // close while loop 
}
?>

<select name="order_id">
    <option value=0>Select Cake:<?php echo $options; ?>
</select>
```

You have html error in this statement because you the html will be like this

```
<option value=0>Select Cake:<option value='1'>what ever</option>
```

so you have to close the first select option so it should be:

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $c_id=$rows['c_id'];
    $options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$c_id\">$cakename</OPTION>";
    // close while loop 
}
?>

<select name="order_id">
    <option value=0>Select Cake:</option>
    <?php echo $options; ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

Now there's only one PHP file which will check for post message. If `$_POST['pet_id']` is present, it will show the item details, otherwise it will show a select-box to the user.

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_POST['order_id'])) {
        $order_id = $_POST['order_id'];
        $sql = "SELECT details FROM $tbl_name WHERE c_id = $order_id";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            // $c_id=$rows['c_id'];
            $details = $rows['details'];
            $price = $rows['price'];
            $picname=$rows['picname']; // this is the name of the picture
            $picture = '<img src="/images/' . $picname . '.jpg" />'; //i change the $pet_id to $picname the pet_id are not inluded 
        } // close while loop 
        echo $details;
        echo $price; // What's the price? You haven't selected price from db...
        echo $picture;
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY c_id ASC";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        $options = ''; // First Create an empty variable then fill it in a loop
        while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $c_id = $rows['c_id'];
            $cakename = $rows['c_cakename'];
            $options .= "<option value=\"$c_id\">$cakename</option>\n";
        }
?>
    <!-- Create a form to send data -->
    <form action="yourtarget.php" method="post">
        <select name="order_id" onChange="this.form.submit()">
            <!-- You are putting all of your options inside the first option tag. Make sure you close the first one and then echo rest of options. -->
            <option value=0>Select Cake:</option>
            <?php echo $options; ?>
        </select>
    </form>
<?php } ?>
```

My idea for images is to store them by their item-id in a folder, you can store image name or path in db. There are too many ways to do that.

Comment: sorry guys, i forgot to change.check it again.and help me thanks

Comment: Your question is still not clear! Is your code working now and you don't know hoe to show pictures? Or you have problems with current code?

Comment: yeah i don't know how To display an image base on the selected value. sorry for my english.

Comment: @asiong_salonga I updated my answer, try it out and if you think it's what you were looking for mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to change the $pet_id to $c_order/c_order,that is the name of select.and i forgot to select the $price from db. @faridv when i select from option, then nothing's happened.no details and price shown.